# RegEx and all phone numbers

Tags: regex, validation, input

I have seen many RegEx expressions for telephone numbers and the one that would seem to work best would be one that allows only the characters that a visitor might use with a maximum of 15 characters

Numbers ( ) . + and spaces with no particular order and 15 characters long.

I know this will not check if it is a valid number but will stop data insertion, etc.

Would this work and could some kind soul please write it out for me.

Thank you,
andy

Comment: I think you should try something first before asking for kind souls to do it for you.

Comment: You can check the reference here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

You can see if what you wrote works here:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: There are some types of coding i can do better than almost anybody else. CF for instance. And there are some that I just can't get right and RegEx is one of them. I help out CF issues when I can and I think it is very unfair to scorn and dock my reputation when I ask a simple question.

Comment: @Andy: That's not how StackOverflow works.  Maybe visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and check the site's rules before you continue this discussion.  See also the [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) for some recommendations regarding this particular topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
/^[().+\d -]{1,15}$/
```

As you said, it's not checking the format of a number nor even telling you if it's valid but it just acts as a way of whitelisting specific characters.

Here's a breakdown of what it's doing:

`/` - Regex delimiter; some languages expect a regex to be wrapped in these instead of double quotes, depends on what you're using.

`^` - Start of line.

`[().+\d -]` - Character set; This one is matching the literal characters `(` `)` `.` `+` `-`  and all digits (`\d`)

`{1,15}` - Iterations; this tells the regex engine to match whatever preceeded it (in this instance, any character from the character set) between 1 and 15 times.

`$` - End of line. This in combination with the `^` means that the regex will only match when the entirety of what is in the field matches the regex. In particular, this means that it's forcing the 15 character limit, and regardless of what is entered, if more than 15 characters are present the match will fail.

Comment: You might want to check that the string contains digits and not just punctuation.  I would go for a string with at least five digits and allow interspersed punctuation between them, but probably not more than one or two per digit.

Comment: Per the OP's request, this is just to whitelist specific characters in any combination or order. I would personally try to restrict users further or have processing after they've entered their values which strips out all non-digits and then evaluate the phone number from there. That may still well be happening after this point, without context of how it's being used we don't know, all I can really do is help with the specific problem that has been presented.

Comment: Thank you bdx. had to eliminate the / to get it to work but seems to do the trick.